# WindowManager$BadTokenException AlertDialog

Tags: android, crash, android-alertdialog

Two users sent me the following bug reports.

First on Android 2.3.7:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4051c190 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:180)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:92)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:244)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:533)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Second for Android 4.0++

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4132f030 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:646)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It seems that the way i use alertdialog is false....
Can anyone show me the best way to use alertdialog?

My Simple Code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle d){
            super.onCreate(d);
            setContentView(R.layout.f);



 exam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        alert.setMessage("Simple");
                        alert.setTitle("AlertDialog");
                        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        alert.show();


                }

                });



    }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code for showing the dialog. Specifically, what is the `Context` you pass to the alertdialog and whether it is an active activity.

Comment: ok but please so me the best way to avoid those bugs

Comment: The code you posted is not the code that causes the stacktrace. For example, the `show()` is called in a message handler and not in `onCreate()` as in the code you posted.

Comment: I use alertdialog using onClickListener but i thought that it was not important

Comment: It doesn't still seem to be that dialog. Note the `android.webkit.CallbackProxy` in the stacktrace, and the lack of any of your code.

Comment: So what is the solution?